# Obtener la moneda definida en Android

Tags: java, android

¿Se puede obtener de alguna manera la moneda que usa el usuario es decir el símbolo: `$, € ....`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ocupar `Locale` de java. Esto te devolvera los valores de la configuracion regional por defecto del usuario.

```
Locale locale= Locale.getDefault();
System.out.println("Locale: " + locale.getDisplayName()); //Localidad
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale); //Datos configurado por defecto segun la localidad.
System.out.println("Currency Code: " + currency.getCurrencyCode()); //El codigo configurado por ejemplo (USD, etc)
System.out.println("Simbolo: " + currency.getSymbol()); //El simbolo que tu buscas, por ejemplo : $, €, etc..
```